# RequireNonce is true (default) but validationContext.Nonce is null

Tags: c#, openid, nonce

I have an app running in azure using Azure active directory.  Some of the users have just reported getting this error trying to access the app.  I can access it ok, so can many other users, its only certain users that are having the issue, heres the error message

IDX10311: RequireNonce is true (default) but validationContext.Nonce is null. A Nonce cannot be validated.  If you dont need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to false

Ive googled it but I cant find a solution, has anyone else experienced this problem ?  How Can I fix it ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412570/owin-openidconnect-middleware-idx10311-nonce-cannot-be-validated

Comment: possible dupliacet what ?

Comment: Link is given in the comment

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but switching back the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect to version 3.0.1 solved the issue

[OWIN OpenIdConnect Middleware IDX10311 nonce cannot be validated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412570/owin-openidconnect-middleware-idx10311-nonce-cannot-be-validated)

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade your OpenIdConnect library again to see if the problem persists? We are running 3.1.0 and it generally works fine. I've seen a couple reports of the IDX13011 error, but I think they are related to users coming from IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Error: IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.

Resolution:
i recreate visual studio virtual directory. i notice while i rebuild the solution there was access denied for the virtual directory. i create new virtual directory by using the project property and the error is gone.