# Url Redirection in Azure Active Directory

Tags: redirect, web-config, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, http-redirect

So I have created a MVC application .net framework that uses Microsoft graph api.and it uses Azure redirect uri for authentication. I had http://localhost:#### and it was working fine locally. now I published the app in IIS and need to change the redirect URI. Azure only accepts something that says starts with localhost or https. I dont have SSL certificate in IIS to do https so I was wanting to make it work with http. Singon url and redirect url are both http?

I have tried bit.ly to redirect to the http. I even registered new app in azure and gave a new signon url and changed on the webconfig. but now it says the page you are looking for cannot be displayed an invalid method of http verb.

Comment: The redirect URL for web apps and services **must begin with the scheme https**. Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#restrictions-on-redirect-urls).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Azure AD has the [Restrictions on redirect URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#restrictions-on-redirect-urls).

If you don't have an SSL certificate, it's a good idea to create self signed certificates for https domain.

You can refer to an earlier post: [Trust a self signed cert from IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641473/trust-a-self-signed-cert-from-iis?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I added self signed certificate to the azure portal but now the error is "IDX10311: RequireNonce is 'true' (default) but validationContext.Nonce is null. A nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'.

Comment: This should be another issue. This issue and its possible solutions have been discussed in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412570/owin-openidconnect-middleware-idx10311-nonce-cannot-be-validated. BTW, have you modified the reply URL in Azure active directory?

Comment: Thanks for the promt response but looks like only way I can make redirect uri work is to get legit SSL certificate for the published app. Self assigned certificate didnot work. Azure would know that url is not legit certficate URL. I will come back once I do this process with legist SSL certificate.

Comment: Yes, self assigned certificate is for test purposes. If the app runs in Production Environment, it should be signed by a trusted certificate authority. Learn more details from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site.

Comment: I am still waiting on my Sys Admin to provide me with a certificate, As of right now I have localhost on azure ad for redirect. @Allen Wu

Answer (score 0):

You can set your Azure redirect uri for authentication as "https://yourdomain.com" even if it's not. Then in your application start:

```
if (environment.production) {
      if (location.protocol === 'https:') {
        window.location.href = location.href.replace('https', 'http');
      }
    }
```

This worked for my Angular SPA Application